# PostgreSQL Error: insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, key, constraints

I have a foreign key constraint on a table and when I’m inserting data I get the following error: 
ERROR: insert or update on table "gl_account_item" violates foreign key constraint "fk_gl_account_id" DETAIL: Key (gl_account_id)=(939) is not present in table "gl_account". SQL state: 23503
…if I query the table I can clearly see that it is:

[image]

Here is the CREATE TABLE statement:

[image]

I cannot understand why I'm getting a foreign key constraint violation error when the id is clearly there in the primary key table.  If I remove the foreign key constraint and insert the data and put the constraint back and run a query with a join on that field everything works and the data is there:

[image]

Please help.